# SSIS Derived Column Transformation Cast Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, casting, divide-by-zero

I have a .txt file as a source, part of the file view is below (All price columns are coming as `DT_R4`)

```
Quantity    Partner Share   Customer Price
1           0               0
1           0               0
3           0.7             0.99
2           1.4             1.99
1          -1.4            -1.99
```

The problem is that I’m using a derived column to create a new column, `Discount`, based on these price columns and for some reason doesn’t want to work when the prices are 0. Derived column transformation below:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)((ABS([Customer Price]) - [Partner Share]) / ABS([Customer Price]) * 100)
```

If I ignore the rows where the prices are 0 everything it’s working  fine, but I need those too :(

I have a guess that maybe it's because the expression will be 0/0 but I don't know how to fix it.

Below are the errors:

> [Derived Column [297]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to
> perform a type cast.
>
> [Derived Column [297]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column"
> (297)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error
> row disposition on "output column "Discount" (376)" specifies failure
> on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
> "Derived Column" (297) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
> processing input "Derived Column Input" (298). The identified
> component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
> specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
> Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Conditional Operator` in expression of `Derived Column` something like below.

```
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)((ABS([Customer Price]) - [Partner Share]) / ABS([Customer Price] == 0 ? 1 : [Customer Price]) * 100)
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I just saw that your solution it's the same as the solution I found, so you deserve the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome anytime!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TRY_CAST` operator and `ISNULL` in case of 0:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)((ABS( ISNULL(TRY_CAST([Customer Price] AS int), 0)) - [Partner Share]) 
     / ABS( ISNULL(TRY_CAST([Customer Price] AS int), 1)) * 100)
```

It looks like some strings can't be converted to integers. Add some error handling to your dataflow and route the error rows to a flat file, so that you can inspect them.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work :( ... This expression is returning errors.

Comment: @Valerica is the same error? it might be coming because of data type mismatch b/w source & destination. Please check your source as well as destination datatype and size. 

For verifying your output datatype you can open the advance editor for Derived Column transformation & check the output column data type for each column

Comment: I manage to solve this issue. Was simple but I had a lost moment I guess. I just check if [Customer Price] is 0 I put 0 else remains as it is: (DT_NUMERIC,18,2)([Customer Price] == 0 ? 0 : (ABS([Customer Price]) - [Partner Share]) / ABS([Customer Price]) * 100)

Comment: @Valerica what was the problem?

Comment: The division by 0 was the problem :/